# Scrambled letter dict python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random

Is there an easy way to make a dict where letters are keys and random letters are values? like this:

```
{'a':'z','b':'x','c':'c'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want from your question, but I suspect what you want is a mapping of letters to a shuffled set of letters. That way each letter will correspond to a different letter; no two letter will map to the same letter.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import random
letters = [x for x in ascii_lowercase]
random.shuffle(letters)
letter_mapping = {k: v for k, v in zip(ascii_lowercase, letters)}
```

We import the lowercase letters from string, and the random module. The third line converts the string `ascii_lowercase` into a list, which we then shuffle with the `random.shuffle` method. This shuffles the list in-place, so it has no return value.
Finally, we zip the two lists together to get a list of `('a', 's')` tuples where the first letter is taken from the unshuffled list, and the second is taken from the shuffled list. The dictionary comprehension then builds a dictionary from these tuples as key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is.

```
import string,random
a_dict = {letter:random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for letter in string.ascii_lowercase}

print (a_dict)
```

and I get

```
{'o': 'c', 'w': 'i', 'b': 'w', 'd': 'j', 'c': 'g', 'z': 'b',
 't': 'c', 'y': 'q', 'n': 'f', 'j': 'p', 'e': 'x', 'q': 'y',
 'f': 'j', 'v': 'a', 'h': 'm', 'u': 'y', 'p': 't', 'l': 'f',
 'i': 'e', 'm': 'o', 'g': 'b', 's': 'n', 'a': 'h', 'r': 'n',
 'k': 'o', 'x': 'a'}
```

but you may actually get a different result (which is fully normal and totally expected).

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a logic like the following:

```
import string   # to access lower case characters
import random   # to access  the method `choice()`

letters = string.ascii_lowercase  # get the lower cases ascii letters
keys = [i for i in letters]       # create a list of lower case letter

# generate a list of random letters.
values = [random.choice(letters) for i in range(len(letters))]

# The actual dictionary
mydict = {key: value for key, value in zip(keys, values)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import random
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict((k, random.choice(string.letters)), k in enumerate(ascii_uppercase))
```